# How can I add MXML objects from a Flex Library into my ActionScript Project?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flash-builder, mxml

I have a few objects made in a Flex Library that I want to now add to my ActionScript Project.

I have added the Flex Library's generated SWC file to my ActionScript project's build path and it sees the objects I made (they show up in autocomplete) yet addChild doesn't work so how do I do this?

Specifically it is a menu screen I'd like to have pop up in my ActionScript project.

I've tried googling a lot of answers but they seem be focused on how to convert MXML objects into ActionScript code, or to make a MXML project which you put actioncode into.

Thank you

Edit:
For a test I have like I said above, a simple ActionScript Project and a simple Flex Library project and the contructor for the ActionScript Project is just this:

```
public function TestASProject()
    {
        var tc:TestComponent = new TestComponent();
        this.addChild(tc);
    }
```

Where TestComponent is an MXML Component with a button in it.
Doing this results in a a compile time error because TestComponent cannot be cast into a DisplayObject, which I get, but I can't find out how else to do it.

Also to be clear, whatever I have to do to compile the MXML objects I will do, I just want to be able to initialize them and add them to the display in ActionScript.   I had hoped that I could accomplish this just by using the SWC but that's where I got stuck

Comment: when you said "yet addChild doesn't work " what did it do? throw an error?  not show up?  can you include some code where you tried to add something from the lib?

Comment: Using a Flex Component outside of the context of the Flex Framework generally won't work well; because there is no SystemManager to execute the createChild(), updateDisplayList(), measure(), and commitProperties() methods.

Comment: If I try to just use addChild it won't compile.

I'll edit to show an example

Comment: Flextras is right; you'll be in a world if pain if you want to get this to work (if it is feasible at all). I think your only option is to convert your AS project into a Flex project. Is this an existing project or are you starting from scratch? Or is it just that you want to initialize your Flex components through AS instead of MXML?

Comment: I have a pretty large and complicated set of projects which work together that have already been written.  My designer wants to use MXML to do all of the UI and I had hoped it would be as easy as generating the SWC file and I add them as DisplayObjects :/